# discord.py Assigning a Message object to a json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

In discord.py, I am getting the bot to send a message. Then, I am getting the bot to assign that message object to a key in a json file. My code is

```
async def testmessage():
    with open('messages.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    channel = bot.get_channel(779563485724934184)
    message1 = await channel.send('hi')
    print(data)
    data['message1'] = message1

    with open('messages.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)

    message3 = data['message1']
    await message3.edit(content='lol')
```

However, when I do this, I get the error `TypeError: Object of type Message is not JSON serializable`
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take fields of the Message object and create a dict with names of fields as key. Take only fields you need.
Then, put this dict in the field `data['message1']`.

discord.Message is not serializable in JSON.

If you want to store the real Message object and when reading your stored data, be able to retrieve it, it's not possible with JSON, you should pickle the object (and even then, I'm not sure that everything will be fine.